# dispatch event in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I could not get the event to dispatch. is there any thing missing in my code?

Application1.mxml:

```
<s:Button x="50" y="10" label="Button" click="dispatchEvent(new Event('buttonToggle'))"/>
```

component1.mxml

```
    [Bindable(event="buttonToggle")] 
    public function disableChk():void {
trace("event");
}
```

Comment: -1 Downvoting question. The answer was given (not by me), user refuses to accept, as with most of the user's questions. Accept answer (as it is correct) and I'll redact.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what do you want to ask but I'll try to explain the code I see.

First, dispatching and listening events are performing by `dispatchEvent()` and `addEventListener()` of [`flash.events.EventDispatcher`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html). So you're dispatching event right. But what about listening? To listen to event you should add something like (in the same MXML class where event is dispatching):

```
addEventListener("buttonToggle", onButtonToggle);
…
private function onButtonToggle(event:Event):void
{
    trace("event");
}
```

What about your example it is not about event handling but about [data binding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fe7.html). And of course data binding relies on event dispatching/handling under the hood but there are some limitations to check if event dispatching works using data binding.

First of all, you're using [function as a source of data binding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64c3d-7ff3.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64c3d-7ff2). And there are to problems with it:

1. Using bindable function without returning value (you have `void`) is non-sense.
2. Even if your function will return value it won't call if there is no any bindings in MXML attributes to this function.

But to solve problem of your code (but not your question) we need to have more information about your goal and more code about your implementation.

For the simplest way of handling events of MXML components within the same component you can use very simple handlers:

```
<s:Button x="50" y="10" label="Button" click="myClickHandler()"/>
```

and:

```
private function myClickHandler():void
{
    trace("Event");
}
```

You can read more about handling events from [the official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63825-7fff.html).

Comment: from the code, I like to trigger the event to my component's function. I forgot how dispatchEvent work as I used to be able to.

Comment: Ok, I press the button, the expected behaviour should execute the function in component1.mxml from the event that dispatch.

Comment: So I answer your question? :)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work when I click it. The "even" message did not appear in my debug console. Using Flex 4.5, something broken?

Comment: What doesn't work? Your code? It hasn't sense. Re-read my answer to understand why. And I've pointed you to `addEventListener()` to handle event. And now I've even added simple MXML shortcut for event handling to my answer. To tell the truth I suggest you to read Flex basics before creating your own software. It is much more better to understand all the mechanics than asking questions on every step.

Comment: there is a bug, never mind, I will post to Adobe bug reporting. Oh, I am a Flex developer by the way and have been doing some commercial works. Sorry, if you think I'm a beginner.

Comment: Can you please add an answer with solution to your post and mark it as answered. It will be very helpful for others with the same problem. Thank you.